# why do perl, ruby use /dev/urandom

Tags: python, ruby, linux, bash, perl

I `strace`'d a simple script using perl and bash.

```
$ strace perl -e 'echo "test";' 2>&1 | grep 'random'
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 3
$ strace bash 'echo "test"' 2>&1 | grep 'random'
$
```

Why does perl need the [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random) for such a trivial script? I would expect opening `/dev/urandom` only after the first use of random data.

Edit: I also tested python and ruby

```
$ strace python -c 'print "test"' 2>&1 | grep random
$
$ strace ruby -e 'print "test\n"' 2>&1 | grep random
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Why do perl and ruby open it with different modes?

Comment: Perhaps for seeding its own PRNG?

Comment: generating random numbers is not a simple matter. /dev/random gives access to "random" data from the machine, so perl uses it. How else are you going to get random input? What is your problem with the way it is done? Do you need "better" pseudo-random numbers?

Comment: I tried the same on my system. It reads just 4 bytes from `/dev/urandom` and then closes it.

Comment: @bytepusher: It reads from `/dev/urandom`, not `/dev/random` (which doesn't affect your point). I note that it does so even if you don't call `srand` or `rand`.

Comment: @bytepusher I would expect opening /dev/urandom only after the first use of random data

Comment: It'd be interesting to test this on 5.20 http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/06/perl-5-20-uses-its-own-random-number-generator/

Comment: This might be related? https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/bb6a367ad5d39a6d163bda06f6788f8e7833b713/util.c#L4513

Comment: @chilemagic: Yes, there's a call to `urandom()` in the `Perl_seed` function. It opens `/dev/urandom` (if it exists) and reads 4 bytes from it. I haven't tracked down how the result is used (and I'm not planning to), but my guess is that it stores the value internally, to be used later when calling `srand` (which can be done implicitly on the first call to `rand`). Why do it unconditionally on startup? Why not. It's hardly going to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: It appears to be platform-specific. I see your results on Ubuntu 14, but on OSX Yosemite there are no random calls using current ruby (2.15), perl (5.18.2), python (2.7.8).

Comment: It probably uses it for things like hash seed randomization. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks, for example.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson - sorry, I misread your question. It may not have read that way, but I could and would have helped you out with that ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try searching for "Denial of Service via Algorithmic Complexity Attacks".

In brief, if a Perl script accepts outside input (from a file, network, etc) and stores that data in a hash, an attacker who can influence the data can exploit the hashing algorithm to deteriorate hashes (O(1) lookups) into linked lists (O(N) lookups). To defend against this type of attack, certain parameters of the hashing algorithm are randomised at program start-up so that an attacker cannot construct a sequence of hash keys that will cause a problem.

This is obviously not specific to Perl.  Any program which uses a hashing algorithm is potentially vulnerable to this type of attack.

Comment: Also worth noting that the reason this is done at startup, instead of the first time you use a hash in perl, is that hashes are used internally - for example in the symbol table.